# function_tester.exe has stopped working

Tags: c, function, addition

In this file I am trying to make something that adds all numbers up to a number entered by a user. Such as, 4: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10. So if they enter 4 it returns 10.

When I run the code I get an error message saying my file has stopped working. Do i have an endless loop?

```
#include "biglib.h"

int main()
{
    puts("Enter any number and it will return all the numbers from 1 to your number added together.");

    // Asking them for their number
    int num;
    scanf("%i", num);

    // then I run a loop, if num == 0 then the program should break from the loop and return 0 in the main function if not run the code inside the program.
    int i;
    while(num != 0)
    {
    // I define "i" to be one less than that of num then as long as "i" is greater than 0 keep running the loop and subtract one at the end of it.
        for(i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
        // in here I do the addition.
            num = num + i;
        }
        // finally I print out the answer.
        printf("%i\n",num);
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have an infinite loop. Also the input is not stored in the `num` variable.

```
#include "stdio.h"  
int main(void) {
    puts("Enter any number and it will return all the numbers from 1 to your number added together.");
    int num;
    scanf("%i", &num);
    int sum = 0;
    while(num>0){
        sum += num;
        num -= 1;
    }
    printf("%i\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some lines of your code seem odd to me.
Why do you use a while loop to test the value of num ?
Why do you put a continue statement as last while loop instruction ?

Remarks:
Your code does not work for negative number, is it the expected behaviour?
You are not testing the scanf return value, which could cause trouble.
I am pretty sure that you should check the scanf prototype.

Hope these questions will lead you to improve your code.

Comment: The code is being tested in a while loop so I can run it multiple times without restarting the program. It tests num to see if it equals to zero. if it does return 0  and end the program. If it does not equal 0 then run the code inside the loop. The continue at the end brings us back to the top of the loop if num doesn't equal 0. So if I enter a number and it returns a value then I can enter another value without having to close and restart the  program. Just a convenience really. The idea is that it does not work for a negative number originally.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, the code you put in your question does not do what you are expecting. Your while loop is located AFTER the scanf. It means the user will enter the "num" only once. If num is not 0, it computes the sum, prints it and accumulate the sum into the next iteration. For example with num=1, you print 1 forever. If you put num=2, then you will see as output 3, then since 3 is larger than 0, the next iteration consider 3 a num and will print 6 ... and so on.

Comment: About the continue statement, you do not need it. The default behavior of a while loop is to go the bracket that ends the block and then come back to the first bracket to make your test on num.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you yadras fro informing me that I had the scanf outside of the while loop that was the problem and now it works when I do this.**

```
int main()
{
    puts("Enter any number and it will return all the numbers from 1 to your number added together.");
    int num;

    int i;
    while(num != 0){
        scanf("%i", &num);
        for(i = num - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            num = num + i;
        }
        printf("%i\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```